# Use cell containing name of a range as input for INDEX function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way to place the name of a named range into a cell and then refer to that cell as the range input for the INDEX function **and** where the range is discontinuous?

For example, let's say I have a named range "TEST1" as A5:C20,F14:H78.

Typically, I could refer to any value in TEST1 using the reference form of the INDEX function.  For example, to retrieve the value in the 4th row of the 1st column in the 2nd area, I would enter `=INDEX(TEST1,4,1,2)`.

However, if I were to then populate cell A1 with "TEST1" and then use the following, it fails with `#REF!`: `=INDEX(INDIRECT(A1),4,1,2)`.

The above INDEX+INDIRECT does work if TEST1 is continuous but fails when discontinuous.

Also, using VBA is not possible.

Comment: I don't think you can.  INDEX isn't the problem, it's INDIRECT that's not liking it.  Ranges with multiple areas appear to be the shortcoming and I can't seem to find a way to get the first area within a multi-area range by just using a formula.

Comment: @Skin: That was my thought as well - that INDIRECT simply can't handle named ranges with more than one area.  I was hoping there might be an alternate method or something I had missed but I guess in reality, this is just a limitation with the INDIRECT function.

Comment: yeah.  Any reason why VBA is not an option?  What about cloud services IF this workbook is stored in SP or something?

Comment: I always prefer a set-up with `CHOOSE` over a volatile `INDIRECT` one. It's true that this necessitates hard-coding each of the Named Ranges in-formula, though if the number of those ranges is small then this approach is not so unwieldly and is more than compensated for by the avoidance of volatility. For example, if `E1:E3` contains "TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3" and is defined as `RangeList` then `=INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,RangeList,0),TEST1,TEST2,TEST3),4,1,2)` gives you your desired result.